# How to rotate around Z axis using transformation matrix in 3D?

Tags: lua, 3d, matrix-multiplication, transformation-matrix

In Lua, I have set up an identity matrix:

```
local ident_matrix = {
 {1,0,0,0},
 {0,1,0,0},
 {0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1},
}
```

This is then updated to contain a point at x=100, y=0, z=0:

```
ident_matrix = {
 {100,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0},
 {0,0,0,1},
}
```

I then define my rotation value as 90 degrees in radians:

```
local r = math.rad(90)
```

From this I create a Z-axis rotation matrix:

```
local rotate_matrix = {
 {math.cos(r),math.sin(r),0,0},
 {-math.sin(r),math.cos(r),0,0},
 {0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1},
}
```

And from here apply the Z-axis rotation matrix to the {100,0,0} point using matrix multiplication:

```
local function multiply( aMatrix, bMatrix )
    if #aMatrix[1] ~= #bMatrix then       -- inner matrix-dimensions must agree
        return nil      
    end 

    local empty = newEmptyMatrix()

    for aRow = 1, #aMatrix do
        for bCol = 1, #bMatrix[1] do
            local sum = empty[aRow][bCol]
            for bRow = 1, #bMatrix do
                sum = sum + aMatrix[aRow][bRow] * bMatrix[bRow][bCol]
            end
            empty[aRow][bCol] = sum
        end
    end

    return empty
end

local rotated = multiply( rotate_matrix, ident_matrix )
```

The matrix multiplication is taken from RosettaCode.org:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Lua

I was expecting the `rotated` matrix output to be the same as:

```
local expected = {
 { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 100, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
}
```

Or perhaps, given left-handed (?) calculations, the Y value would be -100.
What I actually end up with is:

```
{
 { 0, 100, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
 { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and correct my code, please?

Comment: Why you are using 4x4-matrix for storing a point in 3D-space (instead of 1x3 vector)?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I figured the easiest route to success would be to ensure that all my matrices have the same dimensions - though I am aware the rows of A must equal the columns of B.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my identity matrix to be one row of four cells and everything works just fine. #Epic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As implied by @egor-skriptunoff's comment...

In Lua, I have set up an identity matrix:

```
local ident_matrix = {
 {1,1,1,1},
}
```

This is then updated to contain a point at x=100, y=0, z=0:

```
ident_matrix = {
 {100,0,0,1},
}
```

I then define my rotation value as 90 degrees in radians:

```
local r = math.rad(90)
```

From this I create a Z-axis rotation matrix:

```
local rotate_matrix = {
 {math.cos(r),math.sin(r),0,0},
 {-math.sin(r),math.cos(r),0,0},
 {0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1},
}
```

And from here apply the Z-axis rotation matrix to the {100,0,0} point using matrix multiplication:

```
local function multiply( aMatrix, bMatrix )
    if #aMatrix[1] ~= #bMatrix then       -- inner matrix-dimensions must agree
        return nil      
    end 

    local empty = newEmptyMatrix()

    for aRow = 1, #aMatrix do
        for bCol = 1, #bMatrix[1] do
            local sum = empty[aRow][bCol]
            for bRow = 1, #bMatrix do
                sum = sum + aMatrix[aRow][bRow] * bMatrix[bRow][bCol]
            end
            empty[aRow][bCol] = sum
        end
    end

    return empty
end

local rotated = multiply( rotate_matrix, ident_matrix )
```

The matrix multiplication is taken from RosettaCode.org:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Lua

Now, I get what I expected:

```
local expected = {
 { 0, 100, 0, 0 },
}
```